# Removendo linhas de uma matriz em python

Tags: python, opencv

Estou com um problema ao percorrer uma matriz e remover toda a linha se o valor da coluna 1 for maior que 70. Sou iniciante em python, essa matriz é originada da função cv2.HoughCircles, código abaixo:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(grey,
                          cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                          dp=1.5,
                          minDist=45,
                          param1=100,
                          param2=15,
                          minRadius=15,
                          maxRadius=25)
circle = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
```

Se eu dou um print(circle), retorna isso:

```
[[[ 947   67   19]
  [ 788   35   20]
  [ 452   49   21]
  [ 859   67   19]
  [ 193   44   16]
  [ 268   38   16]
  [1027   70   24]
  [  40   34   24]
  [ 398   38   18]
  [ 334   65   17]]]
```

No caso, precisaria remover a linha 6 que contém o valor 70 na coluna 2. Mas, ao tentar rodar um for e usar a função np.delete, a linha não é apagada. Simplesmente não acontece nada.

```
for index, i in enumerate(circle[0]):
    
    if (i[1] >= 70):
        circle = np.delete(circle, index, axis=1)
```

Ele chega a entrar dentro do if, mas não apaga. Tentei printar somente a coluna 1 para tentar fazer uma possível comparação com o if, mas não obtive o resultado desejado, repetiu apenas a linha 1 várias vezes. Código:

```
for i in range (len(circle)):
    for j in range (len(circle[i])):
            print(circle[i][1])
```

Resultado:

```
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
[788  35  20]
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema?

Answer (score -1):

No python não existe "matriz" digamos assim, logo devemos usar a biblioteca numpy como você usou. Portanto para excluir a linha de sua "matriz", utilizaremos:

```
np.delete(circle,(5), axis = 0)
```

A "matriz" gerada é um conjunto de arrays, por isso que só está imprimindo a mesma linha.
Caso queira ver a documentação da biblioteca, também é uma otima referência: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e não resolveu o problema, aparece erro de índice. Já havia lido a documentação anteriormente, mas também aparecia esse erro que mencionei abaixo.

Comment: np.delete(circle,(5), axis = 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in delete
  File "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 5099, in delete
    raise IndexError(
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: tente em outro compilador, um online por exemplo. Isso é erro de compilador esse aqui me ajuda bastante: https://replit.com/~ ele possui python e a biblioteca